# Object required error when executing function

Tags: vba, excel

In my user form I have a textbox and only numeric values are allowed to be input into this textbox, once a numeric value is input and the button next to the texbox is clicked it is supposed to do a calculation on the numeric value and add it to my listbox. When I click the button to add the numeric value I get an error `object required`. Below shows how I am trying to execute this process

```
userInput= Textbox1.Value
List.AddItem executeFormula(userInput)

Function executeFormula(inputs As Integer)
    inputs = inputs * 5
End Function
```

I have narrowed down the issue, the function is working perfectly but it is when I am trying to add the function onto the end of the `List.AddItem`

Comment: I deleted my answer since it was not the problem, but for me this code works perfectly ... can you give more indications about where the error occurs? And add more code?

Comment: take a look at my updated question

Comment: I have figured out the problem, you can't seem to add a function call directly onto the end of `listbox.add`, to resolve this issue I simply added the function call to a variable and then added it to the listbox. Thanks for your help

Comment: No problem, didn't helped much (:

Comment: helped me enough, appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined `Option Explicit` at the top of your code? Is the `List` object correctly named based on what you have on your form? I suspect this is the old VBA equivalent of a null reference exception and VBA isn't able to get a working reference to that listbox.

You could try using:

```
Set List = UserForm1.List ' or whatever the name of your form is.
```

Comment: I have already sorted the issue but I will have a look to see if your answer resolves the problem also, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two small problems:

1. your function should return its result thru the function name
2. you should explicitly add a *String*

starting with a blank "forms-style" listbox:

```
Sub trewr()
    Dim lb As ListBox, ii As Integer
    Set lb = ActiveSheet.ListBoxes(1)
    ii = 56
    lb.AddItem (CStr(executeFormula(ii)))
End Sub

Function executeFormula(inputs As Integer) As Integer
    executeFormula = 5 * inputs
End Function
```